# Converting a tiff file to a sparse object and vice versa?

Tags: r, image-processing, tiff

I am using the [EBImage Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/EBImage.html) package to load multichannel tiff images. My images are to a large degree sparse meaning they contain a lot of 0's. I have a large number of tiff images that I have to read in. This task requires a lot of memory.

I am in no means an image processing specialist but is there a way/package to convert tiff images to a sparse R object with reduced memory usage and then convert it back to tiff images when a specific image is needed for analysis/plotting?

Any suggestions/ideas are appreciated!

Comment: What `R` packages have you looked at for general handling of sparse matrices? maybe `spam` , `Matrix`, or  `SparseM` ?   Certainly a loaded tiff file is just a stack of matrices; you might have to convert from ints to floats or some such.

Comment: I am aware of SparseM. I was hoping that there might be a specific package for this task, which I would prefer rather than creating a custom-made solution. But thanks for the suggestions, I will look into the mentioned packages.